# Can the force on a single gate hinge ever be more than the weight of the entire gate?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, torque, free-body-diagram

This might be an obvious/stupid question, but it's been 20 years since my last physics class...

Let's say I have a gate that hangs on two hinges. It weighs 40 kg, is 4 meters long and 1.5 meters tall. The hinges are placed at 20 and 120 cm from the bottom of the gate.

The hinges will obviously carry the weight of the gate. But of course the top hinge will have some force pulling it out towards the gate, and the bottom hinge will have a force pushing it against the gate post.

So my question is - is it possible that the forces acting on the hinges could be greater than the actual weight of the gate?

I can't really wrap my head around it - intuitively it both seems like yes and no. Yes because there is some considerable torque involved due to the length of the gate, and no because it seems counter intuitive that the forces could be greater than the force required to simply lift the entire gate (i.e. its total weight).

Comment: A torque is not the same as a force: same force can result in different torques, depending on where it is applied.

Comment: Hi Magnus. Consider using a lever. With a lever you can get a force at the short end much higher than the force you are applying at the long end. Yes? Well the gate is acting as a lever with the weight applying the force at the long end.

Answer (score 2):

Consider a lever like this:

[image: Lever]

As we all learned at school, if we apply a force $F$ at the long end we get a larger force:

$$ F' = F \frac ab $$

at the short end, and if $a > b$ then the force applied at the short end is larger than the force we apply at the long end.

Now put a $90$° bend in the lever so it looks like this:

[image: Lever]

So the force at the short end is the same except that it is now applied horizontally not vertically. This is how the forces work in your gate:

[image: Gate]

The force being applied at the long end is the weight of the gate $mg$. If we take the top hinge as the pivot then the horizontal component of the force at the bottom hinge is $F = mg(a/b)$ just as in our right angled lever.

Why did I say *horizontal component of the force at the bottom hinge*? Well it's because there are other forces acting as well. The weight of the gate presses down with a force $mg$, but since the gate is not moving vertically there must be an equal and opposite force exerted by the ground at the bottom of the gate post. This force acts on the gate through the hinges, so assuming the two hinges carry the vertical load equally each hinge experiences an additional vertical force of $mg/2$.

So each hinge experiences a horizontal force $mg(a/b)$ and a vertical force $mg/2$ making the total force at each hinge:

$$ F_{\textrm{hinge}} = \sqrt{\left(mg \frac ab\right)^2 + \left(\frac{mg}{2}\right)^2} = mg\sqrt{\left(\frac ab\right)^2 + \frac14} $$

So depending on the dimensions of the gate the forces at the hinges can be greater or less than the weight of the gate. The condition for the forces at the hinges to be greater than the weight is:

$$ \sqrt{\left(\frac ab\right)^2 + \frac14} \ge 1 $$

Note that $a$ is half the width of the gate so let's replace it by $a = w/2$ where $w$ is the width of the gate, and we'll assume the hinge spacing $b$ is approximately the height of the gate. Then our condition can be written as:

$$ \sqrt{\left(\frac{w}{2h}\right)^2 + \frac14} \ge 1 $$

giving us:

$$ \frac wh \ge \sqrt{\frac32} $$

Though in practice the vertical load probably isn't shared equally between the hinges so this is a best case.

Comment: your diagrams and answer are excellent, but are not the loads really on the post?  Picture a counter weight on the other side and you have ... a suspension bridge!  The torque "hinge" may be at the base of the post, which must be resistant to bending.  The gate hinges do not support much weight, and need only to have good threads on the screws that hold them on (or bolts completely through the post). +1 anyways.

Answer (score 0):

The answers by John Rennie and by Ralf Kleberhoff are correct, so of course this will be the same answer again. But I am adding it because I hope it might be clearer for some readers at least.

[image]

The diagram shows the gate and the forces on it. $w$ is the width of the gate; $h$ is the distance between the hinges.

The gate is not accelerating in the vertical direction, therefore:
$$
F_y + f_y = Mg.
$$
The gate is not accelerating in the horizontal direction, therefore:
$$
F_x = f_x.
$$
The gate is not picking up rotation, therefore the torques on it are balanced. A torque, also called a moment, is given by the size of a force multiplied by the perpendicular distance from the line of action of that force to the point about which we are considering the possible rotation. Let's take the lower hinge as the point about which the gate might rotate, then there is a clockwise torque $Mg w/2$ owing to the weight of the gate, and an anticlockwise torque $F_x h$ owing to the force provided by the top hinge. These must be balanced so we have:
$$
F_x h = M g w/2.
$$

We now have almost all the information we need. The only thing that these equations cannot tell us is how the weight is distributed between the two hinges. The gate could be supported by either hinge on its own. But in a well-constructed gate the hinges will be placed accurately so that the forces tend to be equal, and then the hinges move a little until the normal reaction forces in the gate post resist further motion, and if the material at the two hinges is of similar elasticity then this will result in similar forces. So I will treat the case where $F_y = f_y = w/2$. We thus find that the total force on the upper hinge is
$$
F = \sqrt{ F_x^2 + F_y^2 } = \sqrt{  \left( \frac{Mgw}{2h} \right)^2 + \left(\frac{Mg}{2}\right)^2 }
$$
$$
= Mg \sqrt{ \left( \frac{w}{2h} \right)^2 + \frac{1}{4} }.
$$

A typical case might be $w = 2 h$ or $w=3 h$ so we get $F = 1.118 Mg$ or $F = 1.58 Mg$, so $F$ is larger than the weight by a modest factor. If instead the whole upwards force was at one hinge, then one would get a somewhat larger answer. If one had a badly designed gate, with the hinges close together, then huge forces can arise and then one or both hinges will be pulled out of the gate post.

Answer (score -1):

The closer the hinges are together, the greater the pull/push forces must be to compensate for the weight trying to turn the gate down. So much can be said already from intuition.

Let's do some calculations now.

The sum of all forces (horizontal as well as vertical) must be zero, and the sum of all torques must be zero. Otherwise the gate would start to move or turn in some direction. Let's assume the gate is more or less uniform, so its center of gravity is in the middle, 2 meters from the hinges axis. Its weight is 40kp (using the old unit, 1kp = 9.81N, the weight of 1kg at earth surface level).

Let's start with the torque, and take the lower hinge as reference point. You get the torque by multiplying force with lever.

The torque from the gate's weight is 40kp * 2m. This must be compensated by  the upper hinge pulling at the gate. Its lever is 1m, so it needs a horizontal pulling force of 80kp. [As we took the lower hinge as our reference point, its lever is zero, so doesn't account for the torque calculation.]

Now horizontal forces: The 80kp pulling from the upper hinge must be compensated by 80kp pushing from the lower hinge.

Finally the vertical forces: the weight is a down force of 40kp. It must be compensated by upward forces from the hinges. With every real-world gate that I've seen, the gate and the hinges never match exactly, so it's either the upper or the lower hinge carrying all the weight of 40kp.